# Empty line in Table of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I use a template of my university for my thesis. I have several figures. In the table of figures, I have a blank line under two of the figures. I cannot see why and badly cannot reproduce it in a minimal example. The blank line appears between those two figures:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{graphics/example1.png}
      \caption[examplecaption1]{examplecaption1\footnotemark}
      \label{img:example1}
  \end{figure}
    \footcitetext[Vgl.][674]{example1} 

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{graphics/example2.png}
      \caption[eaxamplecaption2]{examplecaption2\footnotemark}
      \label{img:example2}
  \end{figure}
    \footcitetext[Vgl.][]{example2}
```

This produces a table of figures like the following. The Banl line appears between figure 8 and 9.
[image]
The list is created with `\listoffigures`.
If any further information is needed, I will provide it as soon as possible.

Comment: Which document class do you use? Maybe there is a `\chapter{...}` between those two figures?

Comment: I use \documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside,parskip=half,headings=normal]{scrreprt} .  Yes you are right, those blank lines appear between chapters. how can I fix that?